# Rod characteristic for spinning for small freshwater fish

Tags: fishing

Looking for an idea of the characteristics for a rod (length, action...) before I go shopping. Using small lures, commonly 2-4g bladed spinners or 12 g Toby,  going after small brown trout and Arctic char.

Comment: I don't do much fishing for either of those, but would like to know as well.

Comment: I'd go with an 6-8 footer and light to medium action. Personal preference, no good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion would be to go with an ultralight rod, in the four to six foot range, with five and a half feet being ideal.  An ultralight open face reel to match, loaded with four pound test monofilament compleats the set up.

Comment: Could you add some more details as to why these options?